# create_bucket is not working in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

For the first time I am using amazon web s3. I want to create bucket with the following code:

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3('root', 'root')

bucket = s3.create_bucket('firstbucket')
```

But I get error of socket.timeout: timed out

Comment: It seems that you have an error in your code. Have you created the connection based on [this manual?](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html)

Comment: What kind of error?  i have referred this link https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3998 @Mani

Comment: can you pass the credentials in boto.connect_s3?

Comment: yes.. according to this link http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html check under Creating a Connection.

Comment: Please note that they haven't supplied AWS credentials in `conn = boto.connect_s3()` which means that the credentials are already available in the form of configuration. try to create connection using `conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')`

Comment: conn = boto.connect_s3() is an alternative way. I even tried conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>') but I am getting same error.

Comment: Try [referring this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092056/how-to-create-a-s3-bucket-using-boto3) answer. Also try to use Boto3 Since it has many advantages than boto2.

Comment: ok..i will check. thank you.